# Box2D Farseer Physics Center of Mass and origin inconsistent

Tags: c#, xna, box2d, monogame, farseer

I am using the Farseer Physics library with MonoGame.

In my game I use compound polygon bodies, created with `BodyFactory.CreateCompoundPolygon(...);`, but they have problem.

Their origin is in the top left corner, rather then the centroid like most Box2d objects. Since I need to rotate the bodies around a different pivot point than the top left, I found I can change the center of mass of a body (Body.LocalCenter). This works fine and dandy, and I can rotate the body using `Body.ApplyAngularImpulse(...);` or by changing `Body.AngularVelocity`, but here comes the problem:

Changing the rotation of the body using the methods I mentioned before works fine, and the pivot point used is the center of mass, but if I try to rotate the body by directly changing it's rotation (`Body.Rotation`), it rotates around the top left corner rather than the center of mass.
So in effect, `Body.Rotation += 1;` rotates around a different pivot point than with `Body.AngularVelocity = 1;`

You might be wondering why this is a problem, why I don't just use the methods I mentioned before to rotate the body. The problem is I need to be able to check the current rotation of the body. I can't figure out a way to do this. I can't use `Body.Rotation` since it returns the rotation around a wrong point.

TL;DR: `Body.Rotation` doesn't return rotation around center of mass, how to combat this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the pivot and mass center correctly set if you create your compound polygon from a list of points relative to the center.

For a 20 units side square :
  instead of :  [0,0][20,0][20,20][-20,20]
  use        :  [-10,-10][10,-10][10,10][-10,10]